# getting "authentication required" when requesting / instead of /index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On my server I have the following .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/webinterface/.htpasswd
Options +FollowSymLinks
Require valid-user

<Files index.php>
    Satisfy any
    Allow from *
</Files>
```

If I request the URL "IP-ADDRESS/index.php", everything works fine, I get the index.php displayed without an authentication prompt. However as soon as I request "IP-ADDRESS/" the browser asks me for my credentials.

Why is this the case? What am I missing?

Comment: Wow you had literally the EXACT same problem and setup as me, what a coincidence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replacing the block to use mod_setenvif to check the request URI instead of using `<Files>`. The mod_auth* modules has precedence over mod_dir so the mapping from `/` to `/index.php` doesn't happen until after the auth takes place. Mod_setenvif will occur before the auth. Try:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/$" allow=yes
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/index.php$" allow=yes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/webinterface/.htpasswd
Options +FollowSymLinks
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from All
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allow
```

If the requested URI is exactly `/` or `/index.php`, the variable `allow` gets set. The stuff after the Auth lines say to deny everything except a valid user *or* if the variable `allow` has been set.

Comment: wow, I am deeply impressed. That was a great anser. Thanks alot

Comment: Do you not have to put the block that begins with AuthType into a <Directory>, <Location> or <Files> etc. directive?

Comment: Can you help me understand how to do the opposite of this? I want to allow access to all files and subdirectories within a directory with no password protection, but I do want to require password authentication for / or /index.php. When I password protect the index.php file, I can still access / with no password. I think your answer above contains the rules needed for me to reverse the above and make it work for my case, but I don't understand SetEnvIf etc. well enough to write it up.