# Use htaccess to exclude all files except index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use the .htaccess to exclude all files except the /index.php file and the url without the index.php file.  I am using the following following:

```
#.htaccess

#Look for php before html
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<Files *>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Sorry, Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile  /home/Documents/SystemFiles/apache/passwords
Require user myuser
</Files>


<Files "index.php"> 
Order Deny,Allow 
Allow from All 
Satisfy any 
</Files>
```

Right now everything is password protected except /index.php.  However, what I would like to do is have it so that both www.site.com/ and www.site.com/index.php are not password protected.  As it stands now www.site.com/ is password protected while www.site.com/index.php is not.

Thanks

### UPDATED!!!!

I found this that solved my problem:

[getting "authentication required" when requesting / instead of /index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731109/getting-authentication-required-when-requesting-instead-of-index-php?rq=1)

Comment: This sort of thing would allow for `/subdir/index.php` to be allowed as well. You'd be better off with `<Location>` to allow specific urls

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server config files, so I would like to do this with .htaccess if possible.  Correct me if I am wrong but I believe <Location> can't be used in the .htaccess.

Comment: yeah, lolcation's limited to .conf only, since .htaccess files are implicitly location-specific already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting "authentication required" when requesting / instead of /index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731109/getting-authentication-required-when-requesting-instead-of-index-php)