# How to password protect index.php and /, but allow access to all other files and subdirectories.

Tags: php, .htaccess

My question is very similar to this one:
[getting "authentication required" when requesting / instead of /index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731109/getting-authentication-required-when-requesting-instead-of-index-php?rq=1)

However, in the question above, the goal is to allow access to only the root URL or index.php and to password protect access to all other files and subdirectories.

An excellent answer was given:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/$" allow=yes
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/index.php$" allow=yes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/webinterface/.htpasswd
Options +FollowSymLinks
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from All
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allow
```

My question is the reverse: I only want to password protect the root URL of the directory or the index.php file, and to allow free access to all other files in the directory. When I used `<FilesMatch "index.php">` I succeeded in protecting the index file, but the root url allowed access.

I'm sure the answer is basically obvious to those of you who are more familiar with htaccess than I am. How do I password protect only index.php and the root url? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/(index\.php)?$" PROTECT

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /var/www/webinterface/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
Deny from env=PROTECT
```

- Regex pattern `^/(index\.php)?$` will match `/` or `/index.php` and it sets env variable `PROTECT`
- `Allow from All` allows all the URIs
- `Deny from env=PROTECT` denies env variable `PROTECT`

Comment: I like the answer and the explanation as well, but for some reason when I use your code, there is no password protection at all. Another odd behavior is that when I add index.php to the URL it behaves differently - it removes the index.php filename and shows only the root URL.

Comment: I have tested it on my Apache and it works as expected. Removal of `index.php` seems to be outcome of one of your redirect rule or code. You can move away your .htaccess and test with just this code from a new browser to verify.

Comment: Ahh thank you - I was able to get it to work by creating a slightly more specific regex pattern - I think the example regex was getting wrapped up with a redirect taking place elsewhere. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can bypass this "protection" easily with a request like `/index.php?x`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you really want, but what about the options `-Indexes`, used like this?

`<Directory /www/somefolder>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>`